# Sharing Ethernet, no IP address on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: network-manager, internet, ethernet

A few months ago I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 and since then I have had some strange behaviors that make me think that I might need to just wipe and reinstall Ubuntu.

The latest one is that I am staying at a hotel and have a situation where my laptop gets a much better Wi-Fi connection than another device that I want to use so I would like to route that device through my laptop.  It is on the scope of the laptop getting 10+MB and my other gadget is getting at best 3MB but usually only in the KB for speed.

I have the devices connected to each other by Ethernet cable and on my laptop I selected the "Share to other computers" option on my Ethernet connection.  When I did this at home for the wired-to-wired it assigned an IP address to the shared Ethernet connector. When I'm doing this on my laptop the Ethernet connector is not getting an IP address.  Any suggestions for what I can do or check to see why this isn't getting assigned?

Comment: How is that "wired-to-wired" configured? Aren't all devices connected to the same router/switch? Or do you have two Ethernet cards?

Comment: I had 2 ethernet cards.  The back story of that one was that I was testing an older device for work that needed to connect remotely that was older and didn't support our current VPN client, so I had to route it though another machine that did support it.

Comment: For your other device to receive an IP address, you need something like dhcp server on your notebook. Maybe your PC at home had one installed, but your notebook doesn't?